# A book about a boy who turns invisible

Tags: story-identification

The boy had an electric blanket from Sears and somehow it turned him invisible. He takes off all his clothes and goes to the library to test it out. He meets this blind girl who is freaked out when she brushes his bare skin. There is some reference to "The King and I". The boy has to go to the Sears tower to find a solution.

No idea what the title is

Comment: got any more info did the blind girl and the boy have a story together ? good question and story's interresting

Answer (score 6):

This is the book *Things Not Seen* by Andrew Clement (2002).

An [Amazon.com editorial review](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0142400769) matches the description you provided:

> Teens, especially those not in the über-popular set, know all about feeling invisible. But what would happen if you actually did wake up invisible one day? Fifteen-year-old Bobby is faced with this curious predicament in Andrew Clements's compelling novel Things Not Seen. Doing his best to adapt, Bobby informs his parents and grows more and more frustrated as they try to control his (unseen) life. Attempting to take matters in his own hands, he ventures out--naked--to the library, where he meets a blind girl who becomes a natural confidant. The ensuing drama, involving a nationwide search for other invisible people and a break-in to the computer database at Sears, Roebuck legal department headquarters ("News flash: Invisible people make excellent spies and thieves") is authentic enough in detail to allow readers to overlook the nuttiness of it all. Teens will identify with Bobby's experience of being essentially invisible. Highly recommended. (Ages 11 to 15) --Emilie Coulter

I used Amazon's "Look Inside" feature to search for "The King and I", and it is on page 157:

> It's *The King and I*, the original one with the bald guy and all the singing and dancing.